# Excel , if trust center > macro setting is Enable VBA macros, it will failed to run VBA with runtime error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

[image: In my excel > Macro >setting, if I have set 'Enable VBA macros......']

[image: then when I open an VBA excel and Clicked 'Enable Editing']

[image: VBA run-time error '1004' Method 'Worksheets' of object '_Global' failed]

[image: when click debug, the coding can not run, it can not select the sheet]

[image: And the excel is still in 'Protected View']
[image: but the VBA work fine if I have set 'Disable VBA macros with notification' in Macro >setting and click 'Enable Editing' when open the VBA]

In Excel , in trust center > macro setting: if default clicked Enable VBA macros.
When I open the excel, it will failed to run VBA with runtime error 1004.
[VBA run-time error '1004' Method 'Worksheets' of object '_Global' failed]
and the excel is still in 'Protected View'

**But the VBA work fine if I have set 'Disable VBA macros with notification' in Macro >setting and click 'Enable Editing' when open the VBA

I have created a testing excel below, you could download it and try when you have time.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cP7e4uofhDcH7nOyj52GS3KaBO09vhec/view?usp=sharing

**It is work with placing the excel in a trusted location.
[image: It is work with trusted location https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4]
[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/security/internet-macros-blocked]

Comment: It looks not being a problem related to Macros enabled or not. It looks being related to the place where from the open document comes. If it came from internet download/mail, it is opened in protected view. To avoid such a security approach you should proceed in the next way: In case of downloaded workbooks, right click on the file icon - Properties and check `Unblock` check box to the bottom down of properties window. Then **add** the (suspect) folder where from the workbook has been loaded in `Excel Trusted locations`.

Comment: @faneduru Thanks for the reply. Yes it is downloaded from internet and it is opened in protected view.

However,  in trust center > macro setting, if the default setting is  'Enable VBA macros......' , even I have clicked 'enable edit' , seems like that it is still in protected view and VBA failed. 

But if in trust center > macro setting, if the default setting is  'Disable VBA macros with notification' , when I click 'enable edit' , seems like that it can leave the protected view and VBA can run.

Comment: This may look a little strange. The first option is even more permisive then the second one. But, maybe Excel considers more dangerous opening a 'problematic' workbook (downloaded and not unblocked, not in Trusted Locations) if you do not know too much about it, if not in trusted locations and in the second case you personally accepted to be open with macros enabled. Did you try doing what I suggested (**unblocking and placing the folder path in 'Trusted Locations`**)? This should solve the issue for both cases...

Comment: @faneduru  Yes, this is very strange. 'Enable VBA macros......' should be more permissive !!

I have tried to [unblocking and placing the folder path in 'Trusted Locations`] , it is work, but is there any VBA method that could solve the issue? Since it may be difficult to control the place where user store the excel.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/security/internet-macros-blocked

I guess maybe this is the reason 

"""
Macro-enabled add-in files for PowerPoint and Excel

Macro-enabled Add-in files for PowerPoint and Excel that are downloaded from the internet will have the Mark of the Web (MOTW) attribute. For example, Add-in files with the following extensions:

    .ppa
    .ppam
    .xla
    .xlam

Comment: When the user tries to install the macro-enabled Add-in, by using File > Options > Add-ins or by using the Developer ribbon, the Add-in will be loaded in a disabled state and the user will be blocked from using the Add-in.

Comment: If the user trusts the source of the Add-in file, they can remove the Mark of the Web attribute from the Add-in file, and then reopen PowerPoint or Excel to use the Add-in.

If you have a group of users that need to use macro-enabled Add-in files without macros being blocked, you can take the following actions.

For Excel Add-in files:

    Remove Mark of the Web from the .xla or .xlam file.
    Save the Add-in file to a Trusted Location for users to retrieve.
"""

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/03/11/enable-disable-macros-excel/